# "Package natbib: Bibliography not compatible with author-year citations" error with custom style made in Terminal

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

I'm using my own bibliography style created in Terminal using `latex make bst`. I've tried a few times with different combinations (the only one that works is using the default answers in the prompt window for creating the bst file), but I keep getting the same error `Package natbib: Bibliography not compatible with author-year citations`.

(Already checked similar questions, but no answer to this problem)

Here's my source code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{institut-slawistik-hu-berlin}
\usepackage[german]{babel}

\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Example citation}
    This is an example text with a citation from \cite{burzio1988ItalianSyntaxGovernmentBindingApproach}
  \end{frame}

  \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Bibliography}
    \bibliography{MyLibrary}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Here's the bib info on the bib file (which is also in the working folder):

```
@article{burzio1988ItalianSyntaxGovernmentBindingApproach,
  title = {Italian {{Syntax}}: {{A Government-Binding Approach}}},
  shorttitle = {Italian {{Syntax}}},
  author = {Burzio, Luigi},
  date = {1988-03},
  journaltitle = {Language},
  shortjournal = {Language},
  volume = {64},
  number = {1},
  eprint = {414791},
  eprinttype = {jstor},
  pages = {130},
  issn = {00978507},
  doi = {10.2307/414791}
}
```

And here's the result:

[image]

I really need to solve this style problem, as it's part of my institute's style guides for this and other works. (It's also pretty efficient as a style). So I'd really like to fix using this style. I'll greatly appreciate the help.

Comment: One of the default `makebst` settings (asked very early in the process) is to assume that numeric-style citation call-outs are to be produced. If you want authoryear-style citation call-outs instead, you have to make an appropriate selection.

Comment: Off-topic: You may want to simplify and shorten some of the reference keys. What are you trying to achieve by using a long key such as `burzio1988ItalianSyntaxGovernmentBindingApproach`?

Comment: Another off-topic comment: The instruction `\usepackage[german]{babel}` suggests that your document adheres to pre-1996 spelling and hyphenation conventions. Is this true?

Comment: Your `.bib` file looks like it was exported for `biblatex`, but you are using BibTeX (together with `natbib`) and a `.bst` file. Specifically, BibTeX styles generally cannot deal with a `date` field, they need `year`+`month`. BibTeX styles also generally use `journal` instead of `journaltitle`. They also generally do not support fields like `shorttitle` and `shortjournal`.

Comment: In this example the fact that the entry used `date` instead of `year`/`month` is definitely a problem for `natbib`. Replace `date = {1988-03},` with `year = {1988}, month = mar,` (or drop the `month` if you don't want/need it). (It may be the only problem, but there may be others. We cannot say anything more definitive unless we get to see the `.bst` file.)